# Хочу сделать динамический ввод размера матрицы и ввод её элементов(тоже динамический)

Tags: c++

Но мне пишет что `cols` должен быть константным. Подскажите что делать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Matrix {

    int **matr;
    int rows;
    int cols;

    public:

        Matrix()
        {

        }

    Matrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
        this->rows = rows;
        this->cols = cols;
        this->matr = new int[rows][cols];
    }

    void c()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                cin >> matr[i][j];
            }

        }
    }

    void cout()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                printf("%3d", matr[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score 4):

```
this->matr = new *int[rows];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  this->matr[i] = new int[cols];
```

Не забудьте про деструктор.

Comment: Не только деструктор...

Comment: Это где писать?

Comment: @JekaX-Ray там, где Вы распределяете память для матрицы, - в конструкторе

Answer (score 1):

Если вы храните указатель, то вы должны писать, как минимум, и копирующий конструктор и оператор присваивания и деструктор.    В таких случаях проще сделать класс шаблоным:

```
template <int rows, int cols>
class Matrix {
    int matr[rows][cols];
public:
    void c(std::istream& is)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                 is >> matr[i][j];

    }
    void out()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                printf("%3d ", matr[i][j]);

    }
};
```

Тогда пользователь  укажет размер массива в аргументах шаблона:

```
Matrix<2, 2> m;
m.c(cin);
m.out(); 

                      ^
```